# Removing TCP Options Using TcpClient in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I am using a TcpClient in C# to communicate with a server.

When I view the first SYN request in Wireshark, I see 12 bytes specifying 6 TCP Options in the following order:

-Maximum Segment size 
-NOP 
-Window Scale 
-NOP 
-NOP 
-SACK Permitted

[TCP_Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMKFZ.png) <<< A screenshot of the Wireshark capture

I am using the default constructor of the TcpClient object being passed into the function.

I believe there is a way to specify an option using the Socket.SetSocketOption Method [(described here)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.setsocketoption?view=netframework-4.7.2), however, I wish to remove these options to verify that the server doesn't require them to establish connections.

Is it possible to remove (or perhaps modify) the options that I am seeing in Wireshark?

Here is a small sample of how I am using the TcpClient (instantiated with defaults):

```
public static IPStatus PingThenConnect(TcpClient tcpClient, IPEndPoint serverEndpoint)
{
  IPStatus ipStatus = IPStatus.Unknown;

  // Ping the given IP Address
  ipStatus = Network.PingIP(serverEndpoint.Address);

  if (ipStatus == IPStatus.Success)
  {
    // Connect TcpClient to given endpoint.
    tcpClient.Connect(serverEndpoint.Address, serverEndpoint.Port);
    tcpClient.LingerState = new LingerOption(true, 10);
  }

  return ipStatus;
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide the relevant wireshark elements as text, for posts indexing purpose. Concerning your specific issue, your question is missing one crucial part: what did you try so far to change/remove the socket options ? which one are you looking for ? why ?

Comment: I am looking to remove everything except the first MSS option.  I cannot find any documentation on properties or methods that directly modify or specify these values.